# Как правильно хранить HTML в PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

Работаю с механизмом снапшотов. Вместо хранения и удалённого краулера prerender предпочёл разместить всё на своём сервере. Делаю запрос на страницу, получаю её исходный код и пытаюсь вставить её в базу. К слову, поле `html` в таблице имеет тип `text`. При попытке вставить html в базу получаю ошибку:

> 2018/06/16 16:17:57 [error] 23147#23147: *55450 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "x600"
>   LINE 153: ...age: url('//photo.hotellook.com/static/cities/1000x600/DFW.j...
>                                                                  ^ in /var/www/production/engine/functions.php on line 556" while reading response header from upstream

Ошибка появляется на ссылке на изображение, где указываются размеры, на разделитель `x` между `1000x600`. Предполагаю, что это не единственный запрещённый символ.

Текст запроса:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO snapshots (pathname, html, inserted) VALUES ('{$request_uri}', '{$source_code}', '{$now}')";
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. _Всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку значений переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php и тогда никогда не столкнетесь с подобными проблемами

Comment: @Mike ну только у меня Postgre, а не MySQL.

Comment: Значит используйте PDO. Он работает с любыми СУБД. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php  Особое внимание обратите на синтаксис передачи массива параметров прямо в execute, это значительно удобнее отдельных вызовов bind_value

Comment: @Mike зачем вообще это делать? У меня вся работа с базами выполняется сугубо самим сервером. Пользователи данные не вносят. А если бы и вносили, то для этого есть экранирование, которое исключает прямое использование sql-инъекций. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: 1. это гораздо удобнее, более гибко. 2. Это не перегружает кеш планов выполнения разными по тексту запросами, что ведет к ускорению работы всей БД в целом. 3.  Позволяет многократно выполнять один раз подготовленный запрос - троекратное увеличение производительности, удобно при массовой вставке записей. 4. Экономит массу времени, исключая подобные ошибки. 5. Использование PDO позволяет при необходимости поменять СУБД без изменения кода

Answer (score 1):

Случайно нашёл функцию `pg_escape_string()`, которая помогла решить задачу.